# How to close the file descriptor opened using fs.readFile/writeFile

Tags: node.js

I've legacy code version 0.12.7 which is working **perfectly fine**.

However it is giving **EMFILE** "Too many files open" error frequently.

How can I release the file descriptor opened using:

```
require("fs").readFile(resobj.name, 'utf8', function (err, data)
                        {

                            
                    });
```

Comment: What OS/version are you using?

Comment: Ubuntu 12. Does it matter?

Comment: Ubuntu 12 has reached its EOL in the year 2017 https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases Try to set, `sysctl -w fs.file-max=1000000` https://askubuntu.com/a/1182049/1034948

Answer (score 0):

You will most likely need to read the files in batches, like this:

```
const fs = require('fs/promises');

const files = [...<array of millions of file paths>];

const MAX_FILES_TO_PROCESS = 1000;

let promises;
let contents;

// Process 1000 files at a time
(async () => {
  for (let a = 0; a < files.length; a += MAX_FILES_TO_PROCESS) {
    promises = (files.slice(a, MAX_FILES_TO_PROCESS)).map(path => fs.readFile(path));

    contents = await Promise.all(promises);

    //Process the contents, then continue on the next loop
  }
})();
```

Two observations that may help you:

1. Use `createReadStream` instead of `readFile` because the latter reads the entire file into memory.  If you're handling thousands or millions of objects it's not scalable.
2. `readFile` doesn't return a descriptor because it closes the file automatically.